# How do I convert a list of floats into a list of percentages?

Tags: python, list, percentage

I have this list :

```
list = [
  0.6490486257928119,
  0.2996742671009772,
  0.589242053789731
]
```

I would like to convert it into a list of percentages with one decimal, like this :

```
list = [
  64.9%,
  29.9%,
  58.9%
]

I don't know how to proceed.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use list comprehension. Be aware however, that the result you would like changes the `type` of the items from `float` to `str` because of the percentage symbol that you would like to include.

As a side note: you shouldn't use `list` as your variable name because that way, you are overwriting Pythons `list` method.

```
lst = [0.6490486257928119, 0.2996742671009772, 0.589242053789731]

new_lst = [f'{i*100:.1f}%' for i in lst]

print(new_lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with list comprehension. For example :

```
list = [0.6490486257928119, 0.2996742671009772, 0.589242053789731]

new_list = [ round(x*100,1) for x in list] #each value in list multiplied by 100 and round up to 1 floating number

new_list = [64.9, 29.9, 58.9]
```

if u want to have %, u can convert to string

```
new_list = [ str(round(x*100,1))+"%" for x in list]

new_list = ["64.9%", "29.9%", "58.9%"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print("{0:.1f}%".format(0.6490486257928119*100))
```

---

Part 1:

```
"{0:.1f}%"
```

This is the *"done format section"* the percentage symbol, it doesn't needs explanation... {in here} the formatted text is placed here '0' (zero) is the index of the integer, what we want to format. In here is the **0.649048...x100** . 
The **".1"** specifies the location of the decimal point and the "**f**" is for the ***float***

Part 2:

```
.format(0.6490486257928119*100)
```

And in the end of the ***.format()*** function where we give the integer, or double, or float

REALLY REALLY SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH!!!

Comment: It would be great if you could add some more explanation into your answer. What is this code doing? Why does it work?

Comment: @JeffLewis , Sorry!
I fixed it, but my english is so poor... but I hope it can be understood :)

Comment: I hope it's worked